# How to write a O(n^2) method that finds the largest distance between two points

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an array `int [] nums = {5, 1, 6, 10, 4, 7, 3, 9, 2}`

I want to find the distance between the smallest and largest number in that array in O(n^2) time.  It needs to be O(n^2) time as per the requirements of the assignment.  To do this, I am writing a method called `quadratic`.  So far I have come up with the code below.

```
public static int quadratic(int[] nums) {

    int max = nums[0];
    int min = nums[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {

            if (nums[i] > nums[j])
                max = nums[i];
            else if (nums[i] < nums[j])
                min = nums[i];  
            }
        }

    int maxDifference = max - min;
    return maxDifference; 
}
```

The problem is, when I run that method with array mentioned above, I get a max difference of 0.  I expect 9, since the largest number is 10, and the smallest is 1.  10 - 1 = 9.

My question is, can someone show me how I can change my code so that it properly computes the max distance between the smallest and largest numbers?

Comment: The solution can even be O(2n); so does it actually need to be O(n^2)?

Comment: In this case it needs to be O(n^2) for this particular assignment.

Comment: Here's a simple debugging tip (though hardly the best way to do this), print out the following inside the for-loop: `i,j,nums[i],nums[j],min,max`. Best if you place this after the if-else block. Just be sure to delete that line(s) of code after debugging.

Comment: I was trying to think of a stupid but "natural" way to make this naturally quadratic instead of superficially inflating it to quadratic complexity, since the problem really wants to be solved in linear time. Maybe a way that's sufficiently and naturally stupid without something smart that is superficially made to be stupid is to bubble sort the data and then output the difference between the first and last element. That would be a naturally stupid solution instead of a superficially stupid solution, and I'm thinking the professor will appreciate natural stupidity more.

Comment: Brilliant idea!  I am going to do this instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overwriting the max and mins.

```
if (nums[i] > nums[j])
    max = nums[i];
else if (nums[i] < nums[j])
    min = nums[i];  
}
```

You need to compare the current number with the max/min that is set already. Instead you're comparing the current number with another number, and then overwriting max/min if the condition is true. In this example, at one point 10 was the max, but then you later checked `if(9>2)`, which is true, so you changed `max = 10` to `max = 9`.

Here it is in O(n^2) time, with the outer loop being completely useless.

```
public static int quadratic(int[] nums) {

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {

            if (nums[j] > max)
                max = nums[j];
            if (nums[j] < min)
                min = nums[j];  
            }
        }
    System.out.println(max + " " + min);
    int maxDifference = max - min;
    return maxDifference; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers (as opposed to points on a plane) You can do that in linear time. Find maximum, find minimum, then subtract. So, no nested loops required.

Comment: It actually needs to be in O(n^2) time for this particular assignment.